# Counting occurrences where current value is equal to or less than previous 90 day values

Tags: stata

I have a daily transactional dataset with gaps. I want to see whether a product with a reference price `websiteprice` of $X on date T had an actual sold price `actualsoldprice` $Y >= $X for at least 10% of previous T – 90 days. In other words, for each transaction where `sale_at_or_above_refprice` == 1, we need to count how many times the actual sold price for prior transactions (of a given product) within the previous 90 days met or exceeded that transaction's reference price.

I have included first step results that I am looking for in the `wanted` variable.

My data is as follows,

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str9 orderdate str16 productcode str10 productcategory byte(websiteprice actualsoldprice sale_at_or_above_refprice var7 wanted)
"3-Jan-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 25 . .  .
"8-Jan-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 40 1 .  .
"12-Jan-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 40 1 .  1
"12-Sep-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 28 . .  .
"18-Sep-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 24 . .  .
"20-Sep-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 50 30 . .  .
"27-Sep-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 50 25 . .  .
"11-Oct-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 20 . .  .
"19-Oct-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 35 24 . .  .
"2-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 20 20 1 .  6
"2-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 .  7
"4-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 .  8
"7-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 .  9
"7-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 20 20 1 .  7
"9-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 20 20 1 .  8
"11-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 . 12
"12-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 . 13
"14-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 . 14
"15-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 . 15
"18-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 . 16
"24-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 20 20 1 .  9
end
```

EDIT - I have updated the `wanted` variable and include a `new_wanted`. The difference is taking into account repeated dates with multiple prices. Also including 2 products to run this process by id.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str9 orderdate str16 productcode str10 productcategory byte(websiteprice actualsoldprice sale_at_or_above_refprice wanted new_wanted)
"3-Jan-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 25 .  .  .
"8-Jan-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 40 1  0  0
"12-Jan-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 40 1  1  1
"12-Sep-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 28 .  .  .
"18-Sep-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 24 .  .  .
"20-Sep-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 50 30 .  .  .
"27-Sep-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 50 25 .  .  .
"11-Oct-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 40 20 .  .  .
"19-Oct-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 35 24 .  .  .
"2-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 20 20 1  6  6
"2-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1  6  6
"4-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1  8  7
"7-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1  9  8
"7-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 20 20 1  7  7
"9-Nov-20"  "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 20 20 1  8  9
"11-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 12 10
"12-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 13 11
"14-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 14 12
"15-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 15 13
"18-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 14 14 1 16 14
"24-Nov-20" "MZZ32819-564-282" "Mens Jeans" 20 20 1  9  9
"6-Jan-20"  "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  60 50 .  .  .
"11-Jan-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  70 60 .  .  .
"12-Feb-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  60 60 1  .  1
"12-Jul-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  60 50 .  .  .
"18-Sep-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  50 55 1  .  1
"20-Sep-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  50 45 .  .  .
"20-Sep-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  66 45 .  .  .
"12-Oct-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  55 60 1  .  1
"19-Oct-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  60 60 1  .  1
"2-Nov-20"  "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  70 73 1  .  0
"2-Nov-20"  "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  60 56 .  .  .
"4-Nov-20"  "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  60 60 1  .  3
"7-Nov-20"  "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  50 45 .  .  .
"7-Nov-20"  "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  66 66 1  .  1
"9-Nov-20"  "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  60 56 .  .  .
"11-Nov-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  60 76 1  .  5
"12-Nov-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  60 71 1  .  6
"13-Nov-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  60 26 .  .  .
"15-Nov-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  65 70 1  .  4
"15-Nov-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  67 70 1  .  3
"22-Nov-20" "ADDZ4449-524-645" "Mens Bags"  56 70 1  .  9
end
```

Below is the code that I am trying to adapt for this task. Credit to Ken Chui from STATALIST.

```
gen date1 = date(orderdate, "DMY", 2020)
format date1 %td

local max = _N
gen wanted2 = .
foreach x of numlist 1/`max'{
    capture drop get get_sum
    gen get = actualsoldprice >= actualsoldprice[`x']
    rangestat (sum) get, interval(date -90 -1)
    replace wanted2 = get_sum if _n == `x'
}
replace wanted2 = . if sale_at_or_above_refprice == .
```

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1613003-counting-occurrences-where-current-value-is-equal-or-less-than-previous-values It is widely considered courteous to tell people about cross-posting.

Comment: Even in the revised data example, how can the same product have different website prices on the same day? I suppose this means that price changed on a given day but it is hard to follow that kind of data without extra detail. That is, there is a time order beyond daily date. Or the example is wrong too.

Comment: This is a tough question. You have given an example dataset (thanks), which is hard to follow (not so good) and not showed any code attempting a solution yourself (ditto).

Comment: @NickCox Apologies for not disclosing more information. The initial data was a list of customer transactions. I modify the dataset to simplify the task that I am trying to accomplish. What you see is a set of prices for products on a daily basis. Repeated dates signify that a particular product was sold at different prices on the same day. I have updated my question and will continue to make changes as I find a solution.

Comment: Evidently the problem lies with the data then. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @NickCox Could you please explain what you mean? Always appreciate your insight. What additional information do you need to understand the problem at hand? Or do you mean that you think this problem is not solvable on your end? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this is Catch-22, as I don't know what you don't understand in my comments, and I don't know what I am missing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*Start by converting date to Stata date
gen stata_date = date(orderdate,"DM20Y")
format stata_date %td

*Sort data and product code as stop conditions in while loop expect them to be sorted
sort productcode stata_date

*Create varialbe to store result
gen count_less = .

*Loop over all rows
count 
forvalue row = 1/`r(N)' {
    
    *Only applicable to 
    if sale_at_or_above_refprice[`row'] == 1 {
        
        *Set result variable to 0 for this row
        replace count_less = 0 if _n == `row'
        
        *Initate locals used in while loop
        local true = 1
        local row_skip = 1
        local count = 0
        local last_date = stata_date[`row']
        
        *Loop until any stop condition sets local true to 0
        while `true' == 1 {
           
            *Test if row_skip hits top of data set (i.e row 0)
            if `row'-`row_skip' == 0                                        local true = 0
            *Test that product is same in compare row
            else if productcode[`row'] != productcode[`row'-`row_skip']     local true = 0
            *Test that previous order is within 90 days
            else if stata_date[`row'] - stata_date[`row'-`row_skip'] > 90   local true = 0

            *Test if actualsoldprice is less thatn old websiteprice
            else if websiteprice[`row'] <= actualsoldprice[`row'-`row_skip'] {
                
                * Each date can only be counted once, so test if date is last date counted 
                if `last_date' != stata_date[`row'-`row_skip'] {
                    *Compare row fits condition, add 1 to counter
                    local count = `count' + 1   
                    
                    *Update last counted date
                    local last_date = stata_date[`row'-`row_skip']
                }
            }
            *Skip one more prevuous row
            local row_skip = `row_skip' + 1
        }
        *Add the count result to the result varaible for this row
        replace count_less = `count' if _n == `row'
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution might not scale well if you have millions of observations, but it should still do the job albeit slow.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think row 2 should have 0 for wanted while row 3 should be 1. The reasoning is that for row 2 the website price is 40, the previous dated actualsoldprice is less than 40. The 0 comes from it still being a sale_at_or_above_refprice == 1 but there are no lower previous values (90 days). Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Also, I forgot to point out the double cases in Nov 2 and Nov 7 need to be reconciled and not counted as separate day occurrences.

Comment: I have updated my answer so now it gets the same count for row 2 and 3. You can then run `collapse (sum) count_less, by(stata_date)` to get the sum of all days. If you need this together with the original data you can merge the result of `collapse` with the original data. Please upvote and accept answer if this solved your issue

Comment: While looping over observations seems pessimistic, I note that I tried a direct route using `rangerun` from SSC but concluded that I don't understand the data well enough to make a positive suggestion.

Comment: Dear @TheIceBear Your answer is really close to solving my solution. Would it be possible to adjust code so that it takes into account repeated dates with different prices? The goal is to count the number of Days and not occurrences. I know you mentioned scaling issues, but I am trying to run this by ID as well. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @AdrianRobles, I have updated my answer to make sure that the same date as the start date is not counted and that earlier dates can only be counted once.

Comment: @TheIceBear Thank you very much once again. While not very scalable to large datasets, the code solves the problem at hand.

Comment: It seems to me that the code does not provide the expected description. For example, in the last observation of your example, I am confused why the wanted variable is counted up to 9, while the total number of observations with the price equal or greater than 70 is just 6. Please give out some more clarification.